# how to validate if data has extra key which is not present in schema by using python jsonschema

Tags: python-2.7

I am using jsonschema library to validate data.

json schema:

```
schema = {
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
        "name":{
            "type":"object",
            "properties":{
                "first_name":{"type":"string", "required":"true"},
                "last_name":{"type":"string"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

data:

```
data = {
    "name":{"first_name":"Guido", "last_name":"Rossum", "middle_name":"van"}
}
```

What I want is data can have only those attributes which are present in schema, if extra key is there it should raise error.

In above example data has 'middle_name' attribute but it is not present in  schema so schema validator should raise error.

How can I do it?

Comment: Have you tried iterating over the keys?

Answer (score 4):

Add the `additionalProperties` attribute to your schema:

```
schema = {
    "type":"object",
    "properties":{
    ....
    },
    "additionalProperties": false
}
```